# Multiple Submit button in a rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to implement a "Preview" feature before creating an object for a product. I followed Ryan Bates railscast on doing so, in which he does so by passing a parameter :name with the submit button.

```
<%= submit_tag 'Preview', :name => 'preview_button' %>
```

However, it's not working in my case, don't know why, may be because I'm using rails 3, I can't tell, but I do not see any changes when I add :name => 'preview_button' with the submit button. Can anyone suggest me a solution?

Comment: Please include your controller code that you are using as well.

Answer (score 3):

Adding Paulo's answer, it might be better to route to different actions based on commit param.

We solved using [advanced constraints](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints) in rails.

The idea is to have the same path (and hence the same named route & action) but with constraints routing to different actions.

```
resources :plan do
  post :save, constraints: CommitParamRouting.new("Propose"), action: :propose
  post :save, constraints: CommitParamRouting.new("Finalize"), action: :finalize
end
```

`CommitParamRouting` is a simple class that has a method `matches?` which returns true if the commit param matches the given instance attr. value.

This available as a gem [commit_param_matching](https://github.com/siliconsenthil/commit_param_routing).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add two submit buttons with different names

```
<%= submit_tag 'Submit', :name => 'submit_button' %>
<%= submit_tag 'Preview', :name => 'preview_button' %>
```

then in your controller you need to check the parameters:

```
if params[:commit] == "Submit"
# do great stuff
end
if params[:preview] == "Preview"
# preview great stuff
end
```